# How to use Woocommerce WC_AJAX class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I am developing a shop based on Wordpress WooCommerce.
I use ajax to make calls for data. But i'm doing it with my own functions in function.php file via wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

Yesterday I have found in woocommerce class WC_AJAX. My Question is how to enable events from that class, and how to call them from js.

Answer (score 4):

PHP - Do not wrap in `if(is_admin())` like regular WP ajax actions. WC ajax is on the front end:

```
add_action('wc_ajax_myaction','myaction');
function myaction(){
    exit("Hello. some_var=".$_POST['some_var']);
}
```

JS - The URL to load is `/?wc-ajax=myaction` which can be called with a standard XMLHttpRequest or [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
var data={
    some_var:'some value'
}
jQuery.post('/?wc-ajax=myaction',data)
.done(function(result){
    console.log('ajax request completed. result=',result);
})
.fail(function(){
    console.log('ajax request failed. check network log.');
});
```